# Multi Temporal Images

Tags: remote-sensing, image

I am new to remote sensing, so I would want to clarify my understanding of the meaning of **Multi Temporal Images**.

As far as I understand, *multi temporal images are multiple images of the same  scene acquired at different times.*

Is there more to their defintion, or are multitemporal images just images of a scene X at two different times, *t1 and t2*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Obviously, you aren't limited to just two points in time, but that is only a minor variation.

Multi temporal information is generally used for change detection, but it also provides a good tool to take phenological information into account when doing vegetation classification.

Comment: Yes of course, there can be more than 2 points in time.

Answer (score 0):

temporal means related to time and yes you're correct. We use the phrase temporal for other purposes too. For example we say `temporal resolution` that means the time delay between two consecutive images.
For example temporal resolution of MODIS is higher than LandSat

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your definition, of course.

If you want to experiment with dense time series of optical images at 10m resolution, you might try the SPOT(Take5) data, available here : https://spot-take5.org.
These times series are available on nearly 200 different sites spread around the world, 45 acquired with SPOT4 in 2013, 150 acquired with SPOT5 in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

3 and a half years later..though..I need to correct Mikkel
What he said is kinda true, though it is not used for phenological information. For phenological information, you need time-series. They are quite similar. The difference is, however, that time series have non-independent observations and also work with equal time intervals, which is not given for multi-temporal. Furthermore, time-series need more frequent observations :)